# Counting number of sessions per user

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to calculate the number of sessions (of activity) per user.  A session is defined as an ongoing activity that ends only when the following start timestamp is more than 30 minutes apart. Only the activity's start timestamp is available.

For example: User #1 has 3 sessions despite 5 timestamps - the 1st 3 count as one session as they  have been done with 30 minutes or less of each other.
User #2, #3 and #4 have 1 session each.

I think a lead function would help but don't know where to start.

```
-----------------------------------
| id      | timestamp
| 1       | 3/31/2021  9:00:00 AM |
+----------------------------------
| 1       | 3/31/2021  9:02:00 AM |
+----------------------------------
| 1       | 3/31/2021  9:32:00 AM |
+----------------------------------
| 1       | 3/31/2021  11:00:00 AM |
+---------------------------------
| 1       | 3/31/2021  3:00:00 PM |
+----------------------------------
| 2       |3/30/2021  11:55:00 PM |
+-----------------------------------
|2        |3/31/2021  12:02:00 AM |
+-----------------------------------
|3        |3/30/2021  11:00:00 AM |
+----------------------------------
|4        |3/30/2021  10:00:00 AM |     
-----------------------------------
```

Comment: You should be able to do this using window functions.

Comment: Please never use image when posting code, always use text. It is  a waste of time reproducing a test environment from images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your hunch to use lead/lag was on the right track, and we can try the following approach:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(
                            minute,
                            LAG(session_time) OVER (PARTITION BY USERID
                                                    ORDER BY session_time),
                            session_time) > 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS flag
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT USERID, SUM(flag) + 1 AS num_sessions
FROM cte
GROUP BY USERID
ORDER BY USERID;
```

### Demo

The strategy here is to use `LAG()` to peak at the previous session time for each record, within each user group of records.  If we detect that more than 30 minutes has elapsed, we record a value of one.  Then, we can simply aggregate by user and sum the number of times a new session has begun.